# Не отправляется весь результат findAll nodejs sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Я пытаюсь отправить все полученные объекты Items с помощью `res.send(JSON.stringify(items));`, но отправляется пустой объект {}. Как это можно исправить?

```
Orders.findAll({
    where: {
        userId: req.user.id
    }
}
)
    .then(p => {
        p.forEach(elf => {
            items = Items.findAll({
                where: {
                    id: elf.itemId
                }
            })    
        })          
    res.send(JSON.stringify(items));
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Items.id - обычно primary key.... findAll будет лишним)
В forEach вы перебираете и на каждый результат делаете новый запрос..
Попробуйте вот так

```
const allOrders = await Orders.findAll({ where: { userId: req.user.id } })
const itemIds = allOrders.map(elf => elf.itemId)
const allItems = await Items.findAll({ where: { id: {[Sequelize.Op.in]: itemIds} } })
res.send(JSON.stringify(allItems))
```

Возможно, вам так же пригодится выборка только поля elf.itemId, а не всей строки..

Comment: но я получаю ошибку ко второй строке: TypeError: allOrders.map is not a function

Comment: Возможно, allOrders  пустой или false..
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map
Результатом выполнения map данном примере будет массив [1,2,3,4,5,6]...

Comment: после первой строки я вывожу console.log(allOrders) и получаю следующее 
Promise {
  <pending>,
  [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 291,
  [Symbol(trigger_async_id_symbol)]: 212,
  [Symbol(destroyed)]: { destroyed: false }
}
Но по идее allOrders должно хранить данные после запроса к бд

Comment: async function getData() { await...} возможно вы не обернули запросы await в async функцию..  нужно тестить что у вас не так

Comment: эта ошибка исправлена, но появилась еще одна. Можете подсказать, в чем дело?      
 const allItems = await Items.findAll({ where: { id: {[Sequelize.Op.in]: itemIds} } })
ReferenceError: Sequelize is not defined
Показывает, что ошибка здесь "[Sequelize.Op.in]"

Comment: В файле, в котором используете запрос, подключите
`import { Sequelize, Op } from 'sequelize'`
или как-то так...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46580397/sequelize-op-is-not-defined
`{ id: {[Op.in]: itemIds}`